# Error casting value of type 'UICollectionReusableView' to 'MyApp.CSSectionHeader'

Tags: swift, casting, uicollectionreusableview

I have the following class:

```
class CSSectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

}
```

I'm then trying to cast it like the following:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let cell1 = UICollectionReusableView()

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        // Throws the cast error here:
        let cell: CSSectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CSSectionHeader

        return cell
    } else if (kind == CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader) {
        let cell: UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView

        return cell
    }

    return cell1
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionReusableView' (0x10ff4d140) to 'MyApp.CSSectionHeader' (0x10d775a70).
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to be able to deque header of your custom class you have to [register](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:) this class in collectionview before calling `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind`.

This should look like:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(CSSectionHeader.self,
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, 
    withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader")
```

You can place it inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: For me problem was also in the custom header's XIB file. I was keep getting error until I open the XIB and manually changed class of header view (it was `UICollectionReusableView`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the custom class for the header in the storyboard.
This comes in handy if you are adding the Flow Layout delegate via an extension.

[image: Xcode storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3
in viewDidLoad()

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(CSSectionHeader.self,
forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, 
withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader")
```

Also add the following

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{
    let headerView: CSSectionHeader  = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier:"sectionHeader", for: indexPath) as! CSSectionHeader
    return headerView }
```